# Organization Namespace using REST API

Tags: rest-api, namespace

I am using this query using REST API to get Apex Classes  `SELECT Id,Name,NamespacePrefix,Status FROM ApexClass`. However this returns all my classes as well Manage package classes.

How can I Identify that which classes are from my organization?

Is there any way to get Namespace of my Organization using REST API so that I can differentiate ?

I tried to parse response after OAuth however it does not have organization Namespace in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotted in the Spring `16 release notes under [Changed Objects](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm?edition=&impact=):

> ## Organization
>
> The following new fields have been added:
>
> - **NamespacePrefix**
> - SignupCountryIsoCode—Represents the two-character ISO country code specified by the user for a sign-up request.

It appears it will now be possible to directly query for the NamespacePrefix using SOQL

```
string np = [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization].NamespacePrefix;
```

---

As per [Getting namespace prefix of an org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/getting-namespace-prefix-of-an-org), if you have a known class in the org then you can query the NamespacePrefix for just that and then find the other Apex classes with the same NamespacePrefix in a following query.

Other options:

1. There are further options for a known ApexClass or custom object in [Determining Namespace Prefix in JavaScript and Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28977/102) using the available metadata.
2. When you query ApexClass the fields `BodyCrc, Body, LengthWithoutComments` come back with placeholder values if they aren't in your namespace. [image]. You can just filter out any results with, for example, BodyCrc = -1. I couldn't get these fields to work in a SOQL where clause, so you may need to filter in Apex with the query result.